# How do I create a route that opens an external file?

Tags: 8, routes

How do I create a route that opens an external file?

As an example I have an XML file in my S3 bucket. I need to create a route to open that file from my website.

Is there a way to achieve this without calling a controller? Can I just set a property in the .routing.yml file for this?

```yaml
my_module.index:
path: '/file.xml'
defaults:
  _controller: 'Drupal\my_module\Controller\moduleController::view'
  _title: 'file View'
requirements:
  _permission: 'access content'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to achieve this without calling a controller from the route file?

No, a route needs a controller, no exceptions. If you can find an existing controller/method that does what you need, reliably, then you should use that. If not, you'll need your own controller and method.

Comment: It says `Unable to parse the controller name  "FrameworkBundle:Redirect:urlRedirect"`. The document you have mentioned is for symfony. How do I use `FrameworkBundle` in Drupal

Comment: Oh right, that's for bundles. Answer updated

Comment: You can also make a controller and do a TrustedUrlRedirect, but I don’t know how many files we are talking so it may not be a scalable solution.